# React + MobX + Server-side rendering: How to restore state of components?

Tags: reactjs, mobx, server-side-rendering, mobx-react

I'm using MobX. My App consists of many component-classes. I render it on the server, and now I want to restore (`hydrate`) it on the client.

Is it possible to restore the state of all the components?